# How can I put the data from a pivot table that updates everyday into a sheet and add the new values at the bottom and not inbetween?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table, spreadsheet

Good day, I have read hundreds of these and can not seem to find a way to achieve this.

Problem.

I have a sheet with a pivot table that updates daily at 06:00 from a database. The pivot table also gets refreshed to show the new data. I have a different workbook that get the values from the first column in the pivot table I do this with a simple =DATA!A1 as an example. In the second mentioned sheet where all these are linked (about 3000 values) I have 8 more column that gets captured manually based on the first columns value. Now every time the pivot refreshes some data gets added in-between the data that was there yesterday. This then in turns mixes up the data I have entered Manually.

Is there any way to fill the first column with the data as in the pivot. and then the next day just check if the value exists to just skip it if not add the newly found data to the first empty cell in that column. I think then my manual data should not be effected. There is maybe a easier or more practical way to do this I just can not seem to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Put your data on a different sheet so it doesn't co-mingle with the refreshed Pivot Data. Try the [GetPivotData](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/GETPIVOTDATA-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function so other column data being entered is not going to hurt your data which seemed to require exact column locations.